# How to show the response from server in webview

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing one application.In that I am sending the HTML with java script code to server using web view.And now server also giving the response as HTML.Now i want to show that response HTML in that same web view.How t do this one.

Comment: what type of data you are getting from server  post here.

Comment: Show code of your request sending.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting HTML in response you can use

`[WebView loadHTMLString:@"Your response HTML String" baseURL:nil];`

Comment: At first time when i send the html to server,iam using this method only.After sending my html to server using this method,server giving the response as html.I have to show that response html in the same webview.

Answer (score 1):

This code for ARC. You can convert html data into NSString and load it following code.

```
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourHTMLdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [yourWebViewObject loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

In other way you can load direct html byte NSData data-type load into UIWebView using following method ,

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

And read this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And more conceptually http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 0):

you could format the response from the server, <tag> become &lt;tag&gt;... or you could get the response and escape on the client side...